# Javascript (Vue + Vite) calling Non-Global dynamic function name

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, dynamic-function

I am building a project that passes in a JSON object to config and display my popup modal, and in the config object, I also pass in the the function name that once the button in the modal is clicked, that function should be called. However, I couldn't seem to get it to work and here is my code:

This is the configuration of my modal:

```
configuration = {
    icon: 'question',
    title: 'Import Employees From Google Workspace',
    content: 'Are you sure to import ' + numOfPeople + ' users from Google Workspace to Ceebig One HRM?',
    cancelable: true,
    action: {
      buttonText: 'Import',
      buttonAction: platform.value === 'google' ? 'importGoogleUsers' : 'importMicrosoftUsers'
    },
    parameters: {
      users: selectedPeople.value
    }
  }
```

In this case, the function name I could like to call is `importGoogleUsers`
In my popup modal, when the button is clicked, the `callFunction` method is executed, and here is the implementation of the `callFunction` method:

```
<script setup>
import { execFunction } from "./HRM/controllers/HRMFunctions.js";

const props = defineProps(['configuration', 'open'])

function callFunction(funcName) {
  execFunction(funcName, props.configuration.parameters)
}

</script>
```

The `funcName` parameter, in this case is `importGoogleUsers` is being passed in as a parameter.
Here is the file that has the implementation of `execFunction` and `importGoogleUsers`:

```
function execFunction(functionName, parameters) {
  this[functionName](parameters)
}

function importGoogleUsers(parameters) {
  console.log('function called')
  const { users } = parameters
}

export {
  execFunction,
  importGoogleUsers
}
```

When the button is pressed in the modal, I am expecting to see console log statement `function called`, however I am getting error saying:
[image]

I am not sure why this is happening, please help.

Edit 1: I also tried `window[functionName](parameters)`, same error

Comment: `this[functionName]` should be `window[functionName]`.

Comment: I tried `window[functionName]`, same error @Barmar

Comment: I think modules don't put global variables/functions into the `window` object. These shouldn't be global functions, put them all into an object.

Comment: @Barmar could you please more specific, what does that look like, please

Comment: I'm not sure how it integrates with Vue, but something like `const callableFunctions = {importGoogleUsers, ...}`. Then do `export {execFunction, callableFunctions}`, and then later you use `callableFunctions[name]`

Comment: It is much easier for you if you handle the logic by a switch case: `if(functionName == 'A') A()`